# Is it inappropriate for introducing yourself starts with "Hi! Myself XYZ"?

Tags: sentence-usage

Normally i use this as introductory sentence but someone told me that this is not the correct way to introduce yourself and he recommended me to start as

**Greetings, i am XYZ infront of you all.**

What should i use ?
Is this really a wrong way to start with 'Myself' ?

Answer (score 2):

'Myself' is a **reflexive** pronoun, so you would never use it unless you had already mentioned yourself (as 'I' or 'me') **in the same clause**.  The only exception is if the reflexive is used adverbially (which allows movement): "[As for] myself, I like kittens."